# Exclude files in sonar from commandline

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I want to exclude specific java source files from Sonar. I do not want to make changes in POM. Is there any maven command line parameter to use which would exclude the specific files?

Comment: You should just be able to do `mvn -Dsonar.exclusions ...`

Comment: What should be the path to multiple classes? If my package structure is:
com.falcon.myapp.Base.java and com.falcon.someapp.Sub.java

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to adjust your pom to set exclusions, and in fact you shouldn't. Exclusions should be set from the UI: **Administration > General Settings > Analysis Scope**